# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #93: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView

Tags: android, xml, crash

My app crashes when I run the following code. I have not written any code in the java side aside from the switch. All I've done is create the layout for the app. Any ideas as to why it keeps crashing?

MainActivity.java

```
package lltest.mohsin.com.testicons;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Switch;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Switch chatSwitch;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        chatSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        chatSwitch.setChecked(true);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#111847"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="11"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#111847"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/whitehouse" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#111847"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/whitesettings" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#111847"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/whitechat" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:background="#FFFFFF">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/simplelogo" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:background="#0E1116" />


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="5">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="20dp"
                        android:text="Interests"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="Update or edit your previous interets"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                </RelativeLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="3dp"
                            android:background="#FFFFFF" />


                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/editText"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
                            android:hint="Interest 1"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp" />

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="3dp"
                            android:background="#FFFFFF" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/editText2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
                            android:hint="Interest 2" />

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="3dp"
                            android:background="#FFFFFF" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/editText3"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
                            android:hint="Interest 3" />

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="3dp"
                            android:background="#FFFFFF"/>

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/editText4"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
                            android:hint="Interest 4" />

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="3dp"
                            android:background="#FFFFFF" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/editTex5"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
                            android:hint="Interest 5" />



                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="3dp"
                            android:background="#FFFFFF" />




                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1">


                            <Switch
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Chat"
                                android:id="@+id/switch1"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
                        </RelativeLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_weight="7"
                        android:background="#0E1116"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:baselineAligned="false">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:text="Contact Us"
                                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                                android:textSize="12dp" />
                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:text="FAQs"
                                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                                android:textSize="12dp" />
                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:text="Info"
                                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                                android:textSize="12dp" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

logcat

```
08-13 17:05:11.145    5233-5233/lltest.mohsin.com.testicons I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
08-13 17:05:11.249    5233-5233/lltest.mohsin.com.testicons W/ResourceType﹕ Too many attribute references, stopped at: 0x01010099
08-13 17:05:11.249    5233-5233/lltest.mohsin.com.testicons W/ResourceType﹕ Too many attribute references, stopped at: 0x0101009a
08-13 17:05:11.249    5233-5233/lltest.mohsin.com.testicons W/ResourceType﹕ Too many attribute references, stopped at: 0x0101009b
08-13 17:05:11.249    5233-5233/lltest.mohsin.com.testicons D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
08-13 17:05:11.251    5233-5233/lltest.mohsin.com.testicons E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: lltest.mohsin.com.testicons, PID: 5233
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{lltest.mohsin.com.testicons/lltest.mohsin.com.testicons.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #93: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #93: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
            at lltest.mohsin.com.testicons.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
            at lltest.mohsin.com.testicons.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 24
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:401)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:696)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:632)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:628)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
            at lltest.mohsin.com.testicons.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
08-13 17:05:14.039    5233-5233/lltest.mohsin.com.testicons I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 5233 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Layout XML file: `Binary XML file line #93: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView`

Comment: Which line is 93 in your layout-file?...

Comment: In textView in xml file in textappearance change the "?" character for "@"

Comment: @Mike it starts at this <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="20dp"
                        android:text="Interests"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

Comment: @GmloMalo android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #116: Error inflating class <unknown>

Comment: Change all "?" occurrences by "@" character in textviews